# cannot create instance from local image

Tags: google-compute-engine, grpc-java

I am following a get started tutorial for gRPC, specifically the "Getting Started" example.  I have created the image per ReadMe.  I created the server image locally using Docker for Windows.
I create the Endpoint, I see it in the Console.  I also created a VPC.  I should be able to deploy now.  I am attempting to use the GCE steps in ReadMe.  I am stuck on:

gcloud compute instances create grpc-host --image-family gci-stable --image-project google-containers --tags=http-server --network=default --image-project

I get this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:

- The resource 'projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/gci-stable' was not found

I don't think I missed a step.  But, the error message appears to hint at some missing step.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Container Optimized OS? If not, then create the VM using a standard image, install Docker and then run the image. If yes, you are using the wrong command. (**gcloud compute instances create-with-container**) Edit your question with details.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to look up Container Optimized OS.  Apparently, I have some reading to do.  Then, I will try again.

Comment: If you found a solution for your issue, could you add it as an answer?